# Understanding Javascript's _this, different types of function calls and how to call a function inside a function?

Tags: javascript

I am learning how to reverse engineer an existing javascript code and I've ran into a few issues which is due to my lack of understanding how core javascript works. The code is below along with a screen shot of the comments I have.

The code starts out with **var warper** being declared.

- And then warper variable equals a function inside a function? Why isn't it the usual call of **function Warper()**, but its inside another function?
- I noticed the use of _this. How is that different from the regular **this** that is usually used?
- The #btn-submit id is set to activate when it is clicked on. I can see that it calls the click_submit function, but why is it Warper.prototype.click_submit instead of just **click_submit()**?
- And my final question, which is what I really want to do is call the click_submit function via js without having to click on the #btn-submit button.

### Question: How do I call the warper.click_submit function using js without the need to click a button? I'm trying to integrate this into another piece of my code.

I tried warper.prototype.click_submit and it doesnt do anything. I'm assuming its because its inside a function in a function?

[image]

```
(function() {
  var Warper;

  Warper = (function() {
    function Warper() {
      this.check_compatibility();
      this.attach_ux();
      if (window.SALT_DEFAULT != null) {
        $('#salt').val(window.SALT_DEFAULT);
        $('#salt').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.salt-label').text('Prefilled salt');
      }
    }

    Warper.prototype.check_compatibility = function() {
      if (typeof Int32Array === "undefined" || Int32Array === null) {
        return $('.form-container').html('<p>\n  Sorry, but your browser is too old to run WarpWallet, which requires Int32Array support.\n</p>');
      }
    };

    Warper.prototype.attach_ux = function() {
      $('#btn-submit').on('click', (function(_this) {
        return function() {
          return _this.click_submit();
        };
      })(this));
      $('#btn-reset').on('click', (function(_this) {
        return function() {
          return _this.click_reset();
        };
      })(this));
      return $('.what-salt').on('click', (function(_this) {
        return function() {
          return $('.salt-explanation').toggle();
        };
      })(this));
    };


    Warper.prototype.click_submit = function() {
      $('#btn-submit').attr('disabled', true).html('Running...');
      $('#btn-reset').attr('disabled', true).html('Running...');
      $('#passphrase, #salt, checkbox-salt-confirm').attr('disabled', true);
      $('.progress-pbkdf2, .progress-scrypt').html('');
      $('.progress-form').show();
      return warpwallet.run({
        passphrase: $('#passphrase').val(),
        salt: $('#salt').val(),
        progress_hook: (function(_this) {
          return function(o) {
            return _this.progress_hook(o);
          };
        })(this),
        params: window.params
      }, (function(_this) {
        return function(res) {
          $('#passphrase, #checkbox-salt-confirm').attr('disabled', false);
          if (window.SALT_DEFAULT == null) {
            $('#salt').attr('disabled', false);
          }
          $('#private-key').val(res["private"]);
          _this.write_qrs(res["public"], res["private"]);
          return console.log;
        };
      })(this));
    }; //click_submit

    return Warper;

  })(); // Warper End

  $(function() {
    return new Warper();
  });

}).call(this); // End Function
```

Comment: where should i post it then?

Comment: If you're still around I can answer some of these questions for you. But as karel said, answering them on stackoverflow is too broad, so send me your email address at alxandr@alxandr.me if you like, and I'll send you a slack invite and we can talk about things there. Don't know how much I have time for, but might help clear up some of your questions at least :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code starts out with **var warper** being declared.

> - And then warper variable equals a function inside a function? Why isn't it the usual call of **function Warper()**, but its inside
>     another function?

It is inside another function to create it's own scope. This practice is used mainly to separate non relative code and prevent global variables.

> - I noticed the use of _this. How is that different from the regular **this** that is usually used?

`_this` is just a variable that is set to point to outer `this`. Everytime you call a function it has own `this` (depending on how you called the function). So if define callback inside another function, and you need to refer to `this` of that outer ("another") function, you can save it temporarily to variable. This temporarily variables are usually referred to as `_this`, `that` or `self`.

> - The #btn-submit id is set to activate when it is clicked on. I can see that it calls the click_submit function, but why is it
>     Warper.prototype.click_submit instead of just **click_submit()**?

If you define function on prototype, every instance will use that same function. If you would define it on `this.clik_submit = function(){...}` then every instance would have to have it's own copy of that function. Last option is to just define `function click_submit(){...}` inside scope, but then the function wouldn't be accessible from outside the scope.

> - And my final question, which is what I really want to do is call the click_submit function via js without having to click on the
>
>   ## btn-submit button.

You need to gain access to warper instance to be able to call the `click_submit` function. Without it (and without being able to update the code) it is not possible to call it. But you could consider creating click event on button yourself which would trigger the function. Using jquery this is as easy as `$("#btn-submit").click();`

Answer (score 1):

`Warper` is an object.

```
Warper.prototype.attach_ux = function() {
  $('#btn-submit').on('click', (function(_this) { //2
    return function() {
      return _this.click_submit(); //3
  };
})(this));//1.
```

on //1 'this' refers to the Warper object and is bound to the scope of `Warper.prototype.attach_ux` function.

on //2 `_this` is the name of argument which refers to the value passed at //1.

Since //1 refers to the Warper object the click_submit method is called.

This is IIFE pattern of function invocation.
If you were to call

```
$('#btn-submit').on('click', function(_this) { 
    return function() {
      return _this.click_submit();
  };
})
```

Here `_this` would refer to the click event and we would not be able to access the defined method conviniently. But we are able to pass the Warper object using IIFE pattern and access it easily.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ use this as a reference for IIFE